# What's the detail in "SHA1withRSA"?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, digital-signature, sha1

Innocently， I thought "SHA1withRSA algorithm" was simply operating the plainText with "SHA1", and use RSA/pkcs1padding to encrypt the result of "SHA1"。However, I found I was wrong until I wrote some java code to test what I thought. 
   I use RSA publickey to decrypt the signature which I use the corresponding privatekey to sign with "SHA1withRSA algorithm" . But I found the result is not equal to "SHA1(plainText)", below is my java code:

```
    String plaintext= "123456";
    Signature signature=Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA",new BouncyCastleProvider());
    signature.initSign(pemPrivatekey);
    signature.update(plaintext.getBytes());
    byte[] sign = signature.sign();
    //RSA decode
    byte[] bytes = RsaCipher.decryptByRsa(sign, pemPublickey);
    String rsaDecodeHex=Hex.toHexString(bytes);
    System.out.println(rsaDecodeHex.toLowerCase());

    String sha1Hex = Hash.getSha1(plaintext.getBytes());
    System.out.println(sha1Hex);
    //rsaDecodeHex!=sha1Hex
```

Easy to find that `rsaDecodeHex!=sha1Hex`, where

> rsaDecodeHex=3021300906052b0e03021a050004147c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b

and

> sha1Hex=7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b 。

So, What's the detail in "SHA1withRSA" ?

Comment: Just for the record: you understand that using SHA1 translates to "waste of time and energy"? https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2014/09/09/sha1-deprecation-what-you-need-to-know ... When you start looking into cryptography, better go for algorithms that are recommended to be used in 2017. SHA1 is ... not.

Comment: And just for the record: if you dont get good answers here; consider asking on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, at a quick glance `rsaDecodeHex` seems to be `sha1Hex` padded with a couple of prefix bytes, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @GhostCat It obviously depends on what you use this for, but in this scheme SHA1 serves as just a traditional hash function, while secrecy is provided by RSA. If you need your hash to be secure too (which you probably do), then SHA1 is definitely not the answer.

Comment: @biziclop: this is a signature, RSA doesn't provide secrecy per se. So SHA1 needs to provide some security guarantees in this instance too.

Comment: @biziclop You are right , the prefix is always "3021300906052b0e03021a05000414"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The  digital signature algorithm defined in PCKS#1  v15 makes a RSA encryption on digest algorithm identifier and the digest of the message encoded in ASN.1

```
signature = 
    RSA_Encryption( 
      ASN.1(DigestAlgorithmIdentifier  + SHA1(message) ))
```

See ([RFC2313](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313))

> **10.1 Signature process**

> The signature process consists of four steps: message digesting, data
> encoding, RSA encryption, and octet-string-to-bit-string conversion.
> The input to the signature process shall be an octet string M, the
> message; and a signer's private key. The output from the signature
> process shall be a bit string S, the signature.

So your `rsaDecodeHex` contains the algorithm identifier and the SHA1 digest of `plainText`

Comment: can you help me to find what is the OID of SHA1withRSA ? Both "1.2.840.113549.1.1.5" and "1.3.14.3.2.29"  can't produce the same result compare to the result of  SHA1withRSA when I use Java API to sign

Comment: Take a look to this ASN.1 decoder http://lapo.it/asn1js/#3021300906052B0E03021A050004147C4A8D09CA3762AF61E59520943DC26494F8941B Your signature is using `1.3.14.3.2.29`

Comment: but why 301f300706052b0e03021a04147c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b got the same result by the  ASN.1 decoder you provided?

Comment: I found that 1.3.14.3.2.26 is the OID used by SHA1withRSA in java. and the ASN1SEQUENCE contain a  null element which is different from "301f300706052b0e03021a04147c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494‌"

Comment: I wrote `1.3.14.3.2.29` in the comment. It is a typo. It should be `1.3.14.3.2.26`

Comment: I do not know the internal of ANS.1 encoding and why is a null there. How you got the second result? I've tested your example and produces always the first one.

Comment: `String sha1Hex = Hash.getSha1(plaintext.getBytes());
        ASN1ObjectIdentifier asn1ObjectIdentifier=new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.14.3.2.26");
        AlgorithmIdentifier  algorithmIdentifier=new AlgorithmIdentifier(asn1ObjectIdentifier);
        DigestInfo digestInfo=new DigestInfo(algorithmIdentifier,Hex.decode(sha1Hex));
        byte[] encoded = digestInfo.getEncoded("DER");
        System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(encoded));`
For some reason I don't have time to digout why. If you get the answer, please tell me

Comment: Use `new AlgorithmIdentifier(asn1ObjectIdentifier,null);`