# How to sign an request using PFX certificate in c#?

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography, signature

I'm trying to make use of unofficial API documentation. I need to sign all of the requests with my own certificate, but the docs came up only with Java code to use, here is it:

```
public class EncryptionUtils {
private static final String ALGORITHM_NAME = "SHA1withRSA";
private static final String CERT_TYPE = "pkcs12";
private static final String CONTAINER_NAME = "LoginCert";
private static final String PASSWORD = "CE75EA598C7743AD9B0B7328DED85B06";

public static String signContent(byte[] contents, final InputStream cert) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, NullPointerException {
    final KeyStore instance = KeyStore.getInstance(CERT_TYPE);
    instance.load(cert, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    final PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) instance.getKey(CONTAINER_NAME, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    final Signature instance2 = Signature.getInstance(ALGORITHM_NAME);
    instance2.initSign(privateKey);
    instance2.update(contents);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(instance2.sign());
}}
```

I came up with this code

```
    private static string password = "CE75EA598C7743AD9B0B7328DED85B06";
    public static string Sign(string text, string cert)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(DecodeCrt(cert), password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        RSA provider = (RSA)certificate.PrivateKey;
        // Hash the data
        var hash = HashText(text);
        // Sign the hash

        var signature = provider.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);

    }
    public static byte[] HashText(string text) 
    {
        SHA1Managed sha1Hasher = new SHA1Managed();
        UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] hash = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(data);
        return hash;
    }
    public static byte[] DecodeCrt(string crt)
    {
        return Convert.FromBase64String(crt);
    }
```

but the output differs from the Java's version.
I've tried to temporarily run java task from c# so I would know if it even works, and it is.
Is there any way to write this in c#?

Comment: The default padding in c# and java is different for encryption.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580563/c-sharp-encrypt-decrypt-from-java-aes-cbc-pkcs5padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both codes use for the signature RSA with Pkcs#1 v1.5 padding and SHA1, which is specified in the Java code via [`SHA1withRSA`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42693024) and in the C# code explicitly in the [`RSA#SignHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.signhash?view=netcore-3.1) method via the 2nd and 3rd parameter. Since the Pkcs#1 v1.5 variant for signatures ([RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2)) is deterministic, both codes must provide the same signature (assuming the same data to be signed and the same private key).

If this isn't the case, there are actually only two reasonable explanations:

- First, the encoding used: In the Java code, the data are transferred as `byte[]`, so that it's not possible to determine which encoding is used based on the posted code. In the C# code, in contrast, the data are passed as a string and converted into a `byte[]` in `HashText`. For this the standard-ctor of [`UnicodeEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.unicodeencoding.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_UnicodeEncoding__ctor) is used, which applies UTF16LE and a byte order mark ([BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)). For UTF8 (without BOM) [`UTF8Encoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_UTF8Encoding__ctor) would have to be used. It's *crucial* that the same encoding is applied in the C# code as in the Java code, otherwise different signatures are usually generated.
- Second, the pfx/p12 file: pfx/p12 files can contain [several certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12). In the Java code, [`KeyStore#getKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html#getKey(java.lang.String,char%5B%5D)) references the private key with its alias (the same applies to the certificate), in the C# code, [`X509Certificate2(Byte[], String, X509KeyStorageFlags)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2__ctor_System_Byte___System_String_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509KeyStorageFlags_) references the *first* certificate in the container, see also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.import?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_Import_System_Byte___System_Security_SecureString_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509KeyStorageFlags_). To ensure that the *same* certificate/key is referenced in both codes, the pfx/p12 file may therefore contain only *exactly one* certificate including the corresponding private key.

If this is taken into account, both codes generate the same signature on my machine (assuming the same data to be signed and the same pfx/p12 file).

Finally, it should be noted that in both codes `cert` is used for different objects. In the Java code, it denotes the `InputStream`, in the C# code the *Base64 encoded* binary data of the pfx/pf12 file.

Comment: I've been struggling with this problem, and I figured the second point out, but while creating signature for each of the certificates in the pfx, none of them match the Java's signature. Also, in Java, the cert variable is used for the same purpose, because while calling method I have to pass `new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pfxCert.getBytes()))`, so it goes rather the same. I'll try to tinker around the encoding. Thanks for advice!

Comment: ok, i just realized that the pfx has got only one certificate and i kept importing it everytime i tried to sign something.

Comment: Have you checked if both codes use the same encoding? Currently, the C# code uses UTF-16LE. A match of the signatures can only be expected if the Java code also uses this padding. Is this the case?

Comment: Ok I've changed the encoding of text before hashing to utf8 and suddenly the signatures started to match. Thanks!